# Arduino rosserial problem compilation

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello , i'm trying to compile the examples for Arduino, for example the Hello_World (or whatever) and i got this error:

```
HelloWorld.pde:-1: error: ‘ros’ has not been declared
HelloWorld.pde:-1: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘nh’
HelloWorld.pde:-1: error: ‘std_msgs’ has not been declared
HelloWorld.pde:-1: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘str_msg’
HelloWorld.pde:-1: error: ‘ros’ has not been declared
HelloWorld.pde:-1: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘chatter’
HelloWorld.cpp: In function ‘void setup()’:
HelloWorld.pde:-1: error: ‘nh’ was not declared in this scope
HelloWorld.pde:-1: error: ‘chatter’ was not declared in this scope
HelloWorld.cpp: In function ‘void loop()’:
HelloWorld.pde:-1: error: ‘str_msg’ was not declared in this scope
HelloWorld.pde:-1: error: ‘chatter’ was not declared in this scope
HelloWorld.pde:-1: error: ‘nh’ was not declared in this scope
```

i'm working on ROS Electric, I really Need Help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66423/arduino-rosserial-problem-compilation/) by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2013-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ros_lib should be installed in your Arduino "sketchbook/libraries".  You will have to make the libraries folder and the sketchbook should automatically be generated in the home directory after the Arduino IDE is opened once. Using this command `mkdir -p ~/sketchbook/libraries` and then `cd ~/sketchbook/libraries` to should get you into the right folder. To install the ros_lib in the sketchbook use `rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py .`  As davinci said this is in the setup.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2013-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on 2013-07-03**:
it's dosn't work :/ when i ran rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py  i got this error  [rosrun] Couldn't find executable named make_libraries.py below /opt/ros/electric/stacks/rosserial/rosserial_arduino

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2013-07-03**:
Try installing rosserial from source.

**Comment by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on 2013-07-03**:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup , i did it :/

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you follow all the steps in the [setup](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup)? And copied the libraries? Seems that it can't find your libraries.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-07-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on 2013-07-02**:
yes, i did't por that i don't know what it's going wrong.

**Comment by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on 2013-07-02**:
suppose that the opt/ros/electric/stacks/rosserial/rosserial_arduino/libraries/ros_lib it's copied on the sketchbook folder